# Whats Wrong With This HLSL Shader ?

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, directx-11, vertex-buffer

What am I Doing Wrong ?
if I Compile This Get an Error

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix worldM;
    matrix viewM;
    matrix projectionM;
};

struct VertexInput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct PixelInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
}

PixelInput ColorVertexShader(VertexInput input)
{
    PixelInputType output;

    input.position.w = 1.0f;

    output.position = mul(input.position, worldM);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewM);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionM);

    output.color = input.color;

    return output;
}
```

i get a syntax error at line 2 at the "  {  "

and if i do This

```
    matrix worldM;
    matrix viewM;
    matrix projectionM;


struct VertexInput
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct PixelInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
}

PixelInput ColorVertexShader(VertexInput input)
{
    PixelInputType output;

    input.position.w = 1.0f;

    output.position = mul(input.position, worldM);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewM);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionM);

    output.color = input.color;

    return output;
}
```

i get an unexpected token 'output '

I Got No Idea What Wrong 
Im Still a Noob in Writing Shaders in HLSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined

```
struct PixelInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
}
```

but then later you use

```
 PixelInputType output;
```

Obviously, that won't work. Use the same name.

Comment: lol , missed that 
just a question can u use Nvidia CG with DirectX ?

Comment: No idea, I don't know the former.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe try defining your cbuffer lik this:

```
cbuffer cbPerObject: register(b0)
{
    matrix WorldM:      packoffset(c0);
    matrix ViewM:       packoffset(c4);
    matrix ProjectionM: packoffset(c8);
};
```